# JavaScript Console

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to setup a console in the web browser using form fields.  It needs to behave much like nodejs's repl (command line).  In fact, I will be using the same API in both.

This falls-short because the properties in `context` are only available under `this`.  Can you please suggest a tweak to get this going?  It is ideal if I can keep `context` unchanged, I use this object to loop (via Object.keys(context)` and set properties on nodejs' repl context.

```
var context = {
    debug: 'I am debug'
}

function evalInContext(js) {
    return function() { return eval(js); }.call(context)
}

//This does not need to work, but it 
//confirms that the context is under 'this'
evalInContext('console.log(this.debug)') //prints 'I am debug'

//This really needs to work:

try{
    evalInContext('console.log(debug)') 
}catch(e){
    //not good: ReferenceError: debug is not defined
    console.log(e)
}

evalInContext('var a=2')
try{
    evalInContext('console.log(a)') 
}catch(e){
    //not good: ReferenceError: a is not defined
    console.log(e)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hy8hewq4/

Comment: FYI: you already have a console in your browser, in the devTools : ))

Answer (score 0):

This in no way removes the dangers of `eval`, however you can create some *String* from an *Object* which `eval`s as a `var` statement that you do in your *function* before `eval`ing the other piece of code.

In my example below it is *very important* that the keys of `variables` are valid identifier names and note the values are turned into *JSON* to protect them from tampering across invocations, if you want functions etc you'll have to implement them your own way

```
var variables = {
    variables: undefined, // shadow self
    debug: 'foo'
};

function evalWithVariables(code) {
    var key, variable_string = '';
    for (key in variables) {
        variable_string += ', ' + key + ' = ' + JSON.stringify(variables[key]);
    }
    if (variable_string.length) eval('var' + variable_string.slice(1));
    return eval(code);
}

evalWithVariables('console.log(debug)'); // logs foo
```

You may wish to combine this with another abstraction to achieve your own `this` (as you're currently doing)

You may also wish to put this definition inside an *IIFE* that just returns your custom eval function to protect the references to your `variables` *Object*, etc

Comment: This makes all the variables available: `function evalInContext(js) { with(context) {eval(js)} }` ... It did not preserve the `a` variable however.

Comment: You can't access the scope chain to see what has been var'd